# Can't import packages in Jupyter Notebook or open Spyder from Anaconda. Ordinal 241 not found

Tags: python, package, kernel, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

So I just installed Anaconda on my Windows 8.1. I'm already used to using Anaconda on a MacBook Air, and it has always worked perfectly.
However, i my PC, not so much. When I try to import any package in Jupyter Notebook, an error message appears that reads something like:

"Can't find ordinal (or directorial) 241 in library C:\Users\Igor\Anaconda3\bin\mkl_intel_thread.dll"

And then the kernel just dies.
Same thing happens when I try to open up Spyder.
I've already reinstalled Anaconda mora than once and it doesn't seem to work.

What is happening and is there a way to solve it?
Really need to fix it.
Thanks!